# Ubuntu 12.04 glusterfs volume failed to mount at boot time

Tags: ubuntu, replication, mount, glusterfs

I have just setup 7 KVM guests, all running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit Minimal server to test out glusterfs 3.2.5 from the Ubuntu official repo. Two of them form a mirrored pair (i.e. `replica 2`), and five of them are clients. I am still new to this file system and would like to gain some "hands-on" experience.

The setup was mostly uneventful, until I put in the following into each `glusterfs` client's `/etc/fstab`:

`192.168.122.120:/testvol /var/local/testvol glusterfs defaults,_netdev 0 0`, where `192.168.122.120` is the IP address of the first "glusterfs server".

If I issue either a manaul `mountall` or a `mount.glusterfs 192.168.122.120:/testvol /var/local/testvol` on CLI, a `mount` shows that the volume is successfully imported. But once a client is rebooted, after it comes back up, the volume is not mounted!

I searched the Internet, and found [this article](http://community.gluster.org/a/howto-mount-glusterfs-volumes-on-servers-at-boot-time-ubuntu/), but since I am not running both client and server on the same node, IMHO it's not strictly applicable.

So, as a kludgy "get-around", I put in a `sleep 3 && mount.glusterfs 192.168.122.120:/testvol /var/local/testvol` into each client node's `/etc/rc.local`.  It seems to be able to get the volume mounted on each node, as far as I can tell.

But this is quite ugly, and I would appreciate a hint as to how to resolve this glusterfs-non-boot-time-mounting issue correctly.

Note that I used the IP address of the first "glusterfs server" although the `/etc/hosts` of all nodes have been populated with their hostnames. I figured that the use of IP address is more robust.

--Zack

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: I've got the same problem also. (Ubuntu 12.04, Glusterfs 3.2.5)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but has anoyone worked out how to fix this? (Ubuntu 13.10, Glusterfs 3.2.7)

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution can be adding more nobootwait and direct-io-mode to fstab, try something like this:

```
     serverip:/vol  mountpoint  glusterfs  defaults,nobootwait,_netdev,direct-io-mode=disable  0       0
```

Also, check your /etc/init/mounting-glusterfs.conf and add:

```
     exec start wait-for-state WAIT_FOR=networking WAITER=mounting-glusterfs-$MOUNTPOINT
```

I hope this helps as I experienced similar issue in the past and solved using above combinations/configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if adding some logging to your fstab might help give you a bit more info? See the fstab config options in the admin guide: 
http://www.gluster.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Gluster_File_System-3.3.0-Administration_Guide-en-US.pdf

> ## 6.1.2.2. Automatically Mounting Volumes To automatically mount a Gluster volume • To mount a volume, edit the /etc/fstab file and add
>
> the following line: 
>   `HOSTNAME-OR-IPADDRESS:/VOLNAME MOUNTDIR glusterfs
>   defaults,_netdev 0 0`
>
> ### For example:
>
> `server1:/test-volume /mnt/glusterfs glusterfs defaults,_netdev 0 0`
>
> ### Mounting Options
>
> You can specify the following options when using the mount -t glusterfs command. Note that
>   you need to separate all options with commas.
>
> - backupvolfile-server=server-name
> - fetch-attempts=N (where N is number of attempts)
> - log-level=loglevel log-file=logfile
> - direct-io-mode=[enable|disable]
> - ro (for readonly mounts) acl (for enabling posix-ACLs)
> - worm (making the mount WORM - Write Once, Read Many type)
> - selinux (enable selinux on GlusterFS mount
>
> For example:
>   `mount -t glusterfs -o backupvolfile-server=volfile_server2,fetchattempts=2,log-level=WARNING,log-file=/var/log/gluster.log server1:/testvolume /mnt/glusterfs`

I tend to think that going with IPs instead of names is simpler and more reliable.